# javascript input focus

Tags: javascript, css, placeholder

```
<form id="commentform" method="post" action="wp-comments-post.php">
    <input type="text" aria-required="true" tabindex="1" size="22" value="" 
       id="author" name="author">
</form>
```

I set default value "visitor" to the input box. When focus is in text box or mouose enters it, I want to hide "visitor" string and want to show it when it loses focus or mose moves out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the HTML5 placeholder attribute:

```
<input type="text" aria-required="true" tabindex="1" size="22"
    placeholder="visitor" id="author" name="author">
```

While browser support is not 100% there yet, this will give you a standard way to achieve what you're trying to achieve, without going through unnecessary hoops.

Another thing you can try is to overlay the input element over some text and make it transparent/translucent when not in focus and opaque when in focus/filled.

As of today, [Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/)'s login page uses this trick:

```
<div class="input_wrapper" id="">
    <label for="user_password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="user_password" name="user[password]" data-validation-type="password" value="">
</div>
```

Through CSS magic this becomes:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using WordPress, so you have the jQuery library on your site.

You can use my [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/inputLabel) to achieve this.

### Example

[image: Example]

#### jQuery

```
$('#author').inputLabel({
   customLabel: 'Visitor'
});
```

In this case, I had to specify the label myself, but the plugin works without this by finding the relevant `label` element to the `input`, which should be present for accessibility.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/c33Cz/).

Comment: really good extension if you already have jquery (which in this case is, because of wordpress). adding to my toolset.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Thank you very much for those kind words. Feel free to [contact me](http://www.alexanderdickson.com/contact/) about any issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are up to HTML 5 yet then try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var prompt="visitor";       
var txt=document.getElementById("author");
txt.onfocus=function(){txt.value='';}
txt.onblur=function(){
            if(txt.value==''){
                txt.value=prompt;
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: The problem with this method however is it doesn't play well with validation.

Comment: @alex not doubt it will be some extra work for validation, more so if user enter the same string ("visitor").

Answer (score 0):

Ates Goral's answer looks very interesting. please try it first shot. this is an alternative if you do not want to sweat..:)
i would suggest using a watermark plugin. there are many available.
have used [this plugin](http://daersystems.com/jquery/watermark/) before. worked fine. gives you nice control.
the plugin requires jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Though I too would use jQuery or CSS and a pseudo-class (:focus)....

Here's an easy JS solution that does exactly what you're after. Again, I wouldn't recommend this approach for more than one or two input fields.

`<input type="text" value="Visitor" onFocus="this.value='';" onBlur="this.value='Visitor';" id="author"/>`